# Create a custom document id in firestore in android, instead of generating random one

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I edit this code so I can create my own custom document id in Firestore?

```
users.add(new Accounts(fname, lname, uname, email, pass)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
            Toast.makeText(CreateAccount.this, "Data saved to FireStore", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
             Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Loui, Could you improve the format of the source code to be easier to contributors to help you?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create a custom document id insead of the one that is generated when using CollectionReference's [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#add(java.lang.Object)) method which:

> Adds a new document to this collection with the specified POJO as contents, assigning it a document ID automatically.

You should use DocumentReference's [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#set(java.lang.Object)) method:

> Overwrites the document referred to by this DocumentRefere

If you want to get the document id that is generated or use a custom id in your reference, then please use following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
//String id = usersRef.collection("users").document().getId(); //Gets de generated id
String id = "yourCustomId";
Accounts accounts = new Accounts(fname, lname, uname, email, pass);
usersRef.document(id).set(accounts);
```

Comment: Hey Loui. Can I help you with other information?