# How to create a Firebase Firestore document with user defined document ID?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Image of Firestore Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdjjf.png)

As shown in the above image, all the users are having an auto generated IDs. How do I use the userID of an authenticated user and use it as the document ID inside the users collection?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54487656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is addressed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> ```
> db.collection("cities").document("new-city-id").set(data);
> ```

`"new-city-id"` is the id of the new document, and `data` describes the fields it should contain.